# How to open exe using WebAPI and class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, class-library

I'm creating WebAPI in c# .NET framework 4.6.1. I have taken an empty template, added a controller:

```
 public class InfoController : ApiController
{
    public bool LaunchNotePad()
    {
        AppServices as = new AppServices();
        bool result = as.LaunchNotePad();
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

I have a class library in the same solution which has some methods like below:

```
public class AppServices
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();
        public bool LaunchApplication()
        {
            bool result = false;
            Process.Start("notepad.exe", "SomeName");
            return true;

        }
    }
```

In my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When I host this and run the URL `http://IPAddress/api/Info/LaunchNotePad`, I expect this to actually open the notepad in the server and return true, but it doesn't. Instead it is showing some error like this:

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

In short, I want to call a class library from API which can access the exe files on the server. In this example, I have shown notepad as sample, but in reality it is a exe which we have created. So every time I send the request, it has to open the notepad in the server where it is hosted.

Is this possible? What am I missing in this?

I have added a picture to show what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with opening an EXE. It's entirely related to routing and your controller method.

Comment: @John , I might not have clearly explained in the question. But I want to open a notepad via Web API. Is it possible?

Comment: _"I expect this to actually open the notepad in the server and return true, but it doesn't. Instead it is showing some error like this: The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."_ - indicates that there is an issue with routing, or that you need the `[HttpGet]` attribute. It doesn't matter what your controller method does, the fact is that ASP.NET doesn't know how to route the request to your controller. Therefore it's nothing to do with opening an EXE.

Comment: If you wish to open exe on the client machine while your API running on Server, it's not possible.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , No , I want to open the exe on server where API is hosted

Comment: In that case consider suggestion from @John.... You have the routing issue... not the notepad issue..

Comment: Why dont you use break points to see If you are hitting your method and if so which line is throwing error.

Comment: John has it right. Share your routing and how you're trying to invoke this.

Comment: What happens if you put the [HttpGet] attribute on your LaunchNotePad method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an API Controller it will support the methods GET, POST, PUT, DELETE by default. Add the [HttpGet] attribute to your LaunchNotePad method or change the name of your method to GetLaunchNotePad.